# Revert after Merge, lost code

Tags: git, github, merge

If anyone can help me, looks like we made a rookie mistake using Git.
I had many changes in a branch called test_bundle of which I did a merge into master this morning (I assume this would update Master with the latest code)
I then had a colleague  who needs to work on the same project clone the Main repository and create his own branch called Dayne. He then did a few commits and push onto Github. Within Github I then Merged his changes into master.
Now I see that when I did the original merge into Master it didn't update Master with all my test_bundle code.

How can I revert to the test_bundle branch before I messed everything up (The purple line)?

Can someone please explain what I did wrong?

[image]

Comment: "when I did the original merge into Master it didn't update Master with all my test_bundle code" ! if you merged `test_bundle` into `master` then `master` should have all the changes of `test_bundle`. does not it?

Comment: Did you maybe only merge to master locally, but just forgot to push to origin/master? Also take a look into your local reflog (google git reflog) - it's your safety net. Be careful though, maybe creating a deep-copy (with cp -r or somesuch) of your repo is a good idea.

Comment: Ok sorry It did update Master, but I see now for some reason when I merged Dayne's code into Master it deleted lines and added his code into the file. So he was working on an older version and when I merged his code his older version overwrote my newer version with his added code

Comment: Ok I think the merge pull request #8 messed everything up, How can I revert to before that?

Comment: Ok I managed to fix my problem by reverting and cherry picking my changes